# Store Procedure to Copy One Column value of one table into another table row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I have two table tblDailyCheckIn and tblWeeklyTimeSheet. I need to copy working hours for every employee from tblDailyCheckIn and insert into Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc of tblWeeklyTimeSheet. For Sunday I have done it, now i want to do it for All day. How Can I do it?

```
Delimiter $$
Create procedure usp_tblWeeklyTimesheet_SundayInsert(In P_EmplyeeID bigint, 
P_WorkingDate Date)
Begin
Insert into tblWeeklyTimeSheet(`Sunday`) 
Select workingHours from tblDailyCheckIn where EmployeeId = P_EmplyeeID and 
WorkingDate = P_WorkingDate;
End $$

Call usp_tblWeeklyTimesheet_SundayInsert(1001,'2020-05-03');
```

[image]

Comment: please don't upload images use text.

Comment: that is a called a pivot table and ha stio be programmed. It would look like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413329/mysql-select-group-by-and-transform-rows-to-separate-columns/61416286#61416286